# How to get Chrome Test Browser to not close after code runs in Python?

Tags: python, selenium

Using Selenium 4.00 and Python 3.9.

So I'm trying to automate some stuff such as logging into gmail. Currently selenium opens a chrome window and the site (in this case gmail) and types in the email properly however the chrome window terminates shortly after typing in the email.

Here is my code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())

loginBox = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierId"]')
loginBox.send_keys("email here")

nextButton = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//*[@id ="identifierNext"]')
nextButton[0].click()
```

Was wondering how to make it not terminate after running the code.

Comment: Why do you need to automate logging in though as it already does it automatically

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: It closes cause there isn't anything to execute.

Comment: As @cruisepandey said.. there is nothing to execute and if you don't want to close the window then you can use sleep statements but what do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing  left to execute. All of the script you have written has successfully executed without an error, hence the browser closes.
If you want it to stay there for an extended period of time, go for:

time.sleep(s)